# Ethiopian loyalists won't give me my land

Tags: civilization-5-gods-and-kings

While recently playing a game of Civilization 5 (with Gods & Kings) I seem to have run across a bug with the cultural borders. In the image below the city of Budapest is surrounded by the borders of the Ethiopian empire, which no longer exists. Originally Budapest was a city-state that was conquered by Rome. The Ethiopians and I went to war with Rome shortly after, and while I took out the Roman cities Ethiopia went and took Budapest.

Eventually I conquered the Ethiopians, but for some reason the Ethiopian border continues to persist around Budapest. Any idea how I can fix this? The Great Artists won't let me culture bomb the squares, so that is out.

[image: stuck border]

Comment: FYI, in Gods and Kings the Great Artist's Culture Bomb has been completely removed (so it's not part of the bug here). The border-grabbing has instead been added as an effect when a Great General builds a citadel.

Comment: @DMA57361 Ah, well, that explains that.  I'll have to give the Generals a try then.

Comment: that is the weirdest thing i have ever seen on Civ 5

Comment: Did you try closing and opening the save? Are you sure it's not a glitch in how the borders are displayed?

Comment: @Xantec have you tried re-opening the save as mentioned above?

Comment: @hammythepig Unfortunately I no longer have the save file to attempt this fix. At the time I used great generals to absorb the territory with fortresses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close and reopen the save. Its a glitch; I had the same problem. It's from not being downloaded properly.

Comment: Why the downvote? We don't know if this is the answer, has OP even tried it?